# Flutter SwitchListTile Changing State on AllItems

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, listtile

I am trying to use the SwitchTileList to show all my categories and toggle them on/off however it seems to either not change state/toggle or it will toggle all of them together.
At the moment the code below the showdefault items are on as should be and the rest are off, however it will not toggle any of them at the moment.

```
 return FutureBuilder(
        future: amenityCategories,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AmenityCategories> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 85.0,
                  child: DrawerHeader(
                    child: Text(
                      'Show/Hide Map Pins',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: double.maxFinite,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.categories.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   bool  toggle = false;
                      if (snapshot.data!.categories[index].showbydefault == 1) {
                        toggle = true;
                      }
                      return SwitchListTile(
                          title: Text(
                              snapshot.data!.categories[index].categoryname),
                          value: toggle,
                          onChanged: (bool val) {
                            if (val != toggle) {
                              setState(() {
                                toggle = !toggle;
                               
                              });
                            }
                          });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
```

Comment: you have given same variable for all the SwitchListTile that's why they changing state all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a separate variable for each individual ListTile. Give your category an additional variable isActive and work with it.

```
onChanged: (bool val) {
   if (val != snapshot.data!.categories[index].isActive) {
      setState(() {
        snapshot.data!.categories[index].isActive = !snapshot.data!.categories[index].isActive;                           
  });
}
```